# Has the discoverability of non-English Stacks Overflow been diminished recently?

Tags: discussion, languages

I've noticed more questions on Stack Overflow in non-English languages just recently.

Is this just something that happens sometimes, or has the discoverability of non-English Stacks Overflow been diminished recently?

Comment: There's only 3(?) or so foreign language stack overflows, so not all wrong language questions are able to go elsewhere.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica More like 4, Japanese, Portuguese, Spanish and Russian

Comment: I've, personally, not noticed an increase or decrease in incorrect language posts. I'd be more tempted to suggest that the advent of browsers completely translating a site as you browse it, so that users don't "notice" the site isn't in English is a bigger part of the problem.

Comment: @Larnu I wondered if the lighter footer had something to do with it, as I can't remember what was there previously. The [list of technology-related sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic) does not have all the SO sites listed consecutively. Or maybe something else going on that hasn't been announced yet which has had an unintended consequence.

Comment: I honestly think it's people just not paying attention to the site they are using, @AndrewMorton . With all due respect to our users, some of them don't take the time to look into the problems they are having before they post their question, and I often find that the questions are in a different language *appear* to demonstrate little to no research effort. *If* they haven't researched the problem before they ask, what hope do we have of them paying attention to the site they are using is clearly written in English, not their native language.

Comment: @Dharman If nothing else comes of this question in a while, I'd be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Larnu - Or even be aware their browser is translating the page.  I know when I translate a page into English, it's certainly not automatic, nor is it transparent it's happening.

Comment: Yes, I cover that in my [earlier comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413580/has-the-discoverability-of-non-english-stacks-overflow-been-diminished-recently?noredirect=1#comment883352_413580).

Comment: AFAIK, some users will still get *Stack Overflow ads* (like [these](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2193/2767), [these](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361/2767), and [these](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1672/2767)) that will point to respective localized SO [based on certain condition](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2393/2767): 1) not using ad-blocker, 2) not enabling "reduced ads" privilege, 3) targeted to them (based on HTTP Header request)

Comment: After two months, I can say you were right. Something is wrong. The amount of non-English questions seems to have plummeted recently. I think there's more and more everyday.

Comment: @Dharman Did you mean rocketed rather than plummeted? (Although either is a slight exaggeration.) Please feel free to vote to reopen my question :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for confusion. I am noticing many more now than I did two months ago

Comment: I'm *noticing* far less,¯\\_(ツ)_/¯