# A/B testing on the Ask page

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, a-b-testing

**Update (2021-12-14):** This experiment has launched on Stack Overflow.

Since we announced the start of product discovery for the new [user onboarding project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364572) we have been focused on gathering user feedback and analyzing data. Now we are planning some small experiments around first-time askers to help us gain more insights into the underlying challenges we face. While there are several areas of the asking experience we are investigating for experimentation, like showing potential duplicates and the right sidebar content, the first experiment we are launching is with the content in the modal that is shown to first-time askers on Stack Overflow.

Many users move quickly from registration to asking their first question. Over 50% of users who ask their first question within a week of registration do it in less than 15 minutes. This doesn't leave a lot of time to engage with help content and the current modal has ~1% clickthrough rate on the "search the site" call to action (CTA). This may be because users are reluctant to engage with anything that stands in the way of posting their burning questions, or it may be because the guidance in the modal isn't engaging or relevant.

This is what our experiments will focus on: can we surface content to new users that engages them and helps improve their question quality? For this first experiment, we are planning a copy change to the ["Asking a good question" modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513) that appears the first-time a user visits the ask page.

### Updating the first-time asker modal

Our goal for this change is to provide first-time askers (this modal only shows to accounts with no previous questions) with guidance they are most likely to need for their first question. These are the A and B versions of the modal. A is the current view and B is the experimental view:

[image: side by side comparison of the 'current modal' and the 'new experimental modal', containing new advice for askers as detailed below]

| Modal part | Current modal | New experimental modal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title | Asking a good question | Asking a good question |
| First Paragraph | You're ready to ask your first programming-related question and the community is here to help! To get you the best answers, we've provided some guidance: | About 30% of first questions do not contain enough code and are closed. Closed questions cannot be answered. Learn about providing a reproducible example. |
| Second Paragraph | Before you post, [search the site](//stackoverflow.com/search) to make sure your question hasn't been answered | Here are some tips for success on Stack Overflow: |
| 1. | Summarize the problem | Provide a detailed description of your problem and what you've tried |
| 2. | Describe what you've tried | Make sure your question is on topic for the site |
| 3. | When appropriate, show some code | Check to see if your question has already been answered |
| 4. |  | Ask one question per post |
| Closing Paragraph | You'll find more tips in the sidebar. | You'll find more tips in the sidebar. |
| Button and Link | Start Writing. Don't show me this again | Start Writing. Don't show me this again |

**Update (2021-12-14):** New image with updated content based on community feedback. The top paragraph and list item 4 have been updated. For the original version see the edit history.

When we reviewed why first questions are closed we noticed that the current modal copy doesn't align well with the top reasons first questions get closed. For example, being a duplicate is not the top reason that first questions get closed, but it is a prominent CTA in the existing modal. Meanwhile, in the First Question Review Queue, "Question Needs Code" is one of the top outcomes and "Question Has Too Much Code" is the least common outcome and the [MRE help page](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can teach users about what is needed for reproducibility. As a result, we've changed the first CTA on the modal to focus on the MRE instead of searching for duplicates. Similarly, we structured the numbered list to give top close reasons higher ranking. The new guidance brings the content in the modal inline with the problems that first-time askers often face and we are hoping this change will increase question quality.

Our null hypothesis is that more relevant copy will not improve question quality (measured by % of closed questions). We are not changing the logic behind how the modal shows today, so if you are in the variant group the only changes you see will be to the modal content. If you have asked a question before, then you won’t see this modal at all.

### What's next?

As stated above, we are exploring other small experiments that aim to improve new users' first questions and can help us learn more about what resonates with these users. You may see some of these experiments over the next few months and we'll share what we've learned from them in a future post. If you have any suggestions on aspects of the new user experience, and first questions in particular, that could benefit from similar experiments let us know.

Comment: The new variant seems like a solid improvement overall. Even if question quality does not improve, I'd prefer it, since it may give people insight in why their question failed. After thinking up a question, deciding to create an account and pressing _Ask question_, there already is a substantial commitment to ask it, even if it's off-topic. A more informative dialog may have benefits outside of direct improvements to question quality, such as less confusion when a question is received poorly.

Comment: Looks good so far. Although I think the "Don't show me this again" link should be hidden at first. Otherwise, new users can simply dismiss it without reading anything and write a poor quality question anyway. Maybe it would make sense to show this modal every time a user writes a question until they have a reasonable amount of positive/neutral voted questions, and only then offer them the link to hide the modal?

Comment: Are there any plans to implement something like this for Meta as well? It would be nice to let first time posters on meta know that they are on Meta. Far too often do we see people posting coding questions here. *Though, if they haven't noticed that they are on meta, I suppose do we have any hope of them reading a model on what meta is?*

Comment: The Start writing button shouldn't be visible before the user has clicked all the provided links.

Comment: Minor nitpick: _Define one question at a time_ is strange wording and I fear nonnative speakers may have problems with it (I imagine it might encourage more _Q1: ... Q2: ..._ posts. I'd change it to either _Ask one question at a time_ or _Post one question at a time_.

Comment: "Provide a reproducible example" should be in the bullets instead of the intro paragraph. Lots of people will skip paragraphs and only skim bullets.

Comment: @ErikA 100%, and I think even native speakers will be misled. Any **new user** could easily interpret the current wording to mean: _Clearly define Q1, Q2, ..., Qn in your post_.

Comment: `do not contain enough code` ....... I might lean towards `the right minimal code`..... Is asking users to take the tour as a bullet too far? I guess the new(ish) tooling helps more with formatting code etc?

Comment: @ErikA "The new variant..." Was thinking about viruses when reading that, but never mind. This is indeed an improvement even if only because it means searching.

Comment: Any chance we could add "post code as text, not screenshots" in there? That's one of the most common problems I see - there isn't a close reason specifically for it, but it's still more common (in the tags I frequent) than asking multiple questions in one.

Comment: Have you looked into the usefulness of the proposed duplicates you present? Given how badly the site's search functionality sucks otherwise, I find it hard to imagine that the links to existing questions would include a relevant one in the top three.

Comment: Once the user has submitted their question, could there be a pop-up letting them know that they should come back in a few minutes to see if there are any immediate requests for clarification? I think that if the user responded quickly then the incidences of being crushed by downvotes and close votes could be reduced.

Comment: There are a lot of changes here, each of which could be good or bad. Arguably the only reasonable conclusions one can reach from this test is *these particular changes* are good or bad and only the affirmative that this dialog affects question quality in some way (if there's a significant positive or negative difference in quality). You can't reject the hypothesis that a more relevant copy will not improve question quality if there's no significant difference in quality, because it may simply be that the particular changes don't make such a big difference or roughly cancel one another out.

Comment: good step into the right direction, IMO - _if the user is inclined to spend a bit of time to learn asking_ - if not they will start writing immediately ;) Many simply don't click references and even if they do, they don't really read the content. An alternative might be to go without any bullets and change the first paragraph to something like (in a friendlier variant ;) "__BEWARE__: the community expects you to put some effort into your question to make it __answerable__, otherwise you might not get __any__ answers!" were effort might a button to expand the dialog now containing the bullets.

Comment: I agree with most comments: good step in the right direction, and check for existing answers should be the first point, not the third. Hopefully this will improve questions and help the "elitist veterans" be less annoyed, so that I might actually use SO again once they stop closing every doubtful question 5 seconds after it has been posted.

Comment: How much code is enough anyway? Some needs more. Some needs less. Some needs all. Some needs none.

Comment: It would be really nice if the people making decisions around here actually used and understood the platform. If that were the case, they would have seen that no one reads any of that, absolutely no one is clicking through any of those hidden blue links, and surely this has been done a dozen times already.

Comment: @ErikA Taking your feedback on "Define one question at a time" into account, we're going to revisit that language. I'll update the post when it's finalized.

Comment: "When we reviewed why first questions are closed we noticed that the current modal copy doesn't align well with the top reasons first questions get closed." Isn't that just survivorship bias at work? If the modal does work at all, one should expect that the close reasons addresses by it won't apply to question as much.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's totally possible and we can look at rates of closure per close reasons in the experiment to see if shows up. With the clickthrough rate of 1% on the "search the site" CTA, we suspect that users simply aren't engaging with the current modal and that the risk of survivorship bias is low.

Comment: What I am missing would have to happen between registration and the dialog for the "Ask Question" button. I am referring to an attempt to prevent those many new users from asking a question by clicking the "Post Your Answer" button. I increasingly get the impression that the "Ask Question" button is too well hidden and should be next to the "Post Your Answer" button. New users often have the wrong impression of reading a discussion thread on exactly their topic and want to pariticipate by adding their question. They totally fail to see the TWO buttons and click the wrong but only visible one.

Comment: Why weren't any previous A/B tests referenced here? There has been extensive testing done on this feature, especially with the partial launches of Mentorship and the Ask a Question Wizard.

Comment: Still, it is disappointing to see that during the testing users who *do* read the modal will take from it that they need to post walls of code, botched attempts, and heaps of logs instead of asking a concise "how-to" question. When we ask for MCVE, we do not mean that only debugging questions are on-topic, but that *if* the question is a debugging one, *then* add code. Please bring the "where appropriate" back to the modal.

Comment: Might it be worth doing this after they have written their question, let them stop focusing on asking and when they click the post button, it shows this with checkboxes, you could even potentially lock those tick boxes because that account has not visited page required for this checkbox.

Comment: I see that you are updating this page here as the testing progresses. Please make sure to post a separate question for the results and any related discussion.

Comment: Why does the post author only have 1 reputation??

Comment: @code are you concerned because meta generally requires at least 5 rep? If so, staff is exempt from that limitation.

Comment: @Catija this post is upvoted, but the staff has no reputation...

Comment: @code it's meta. One doesn't earn reputation on meta sites other than meta stack exchange.

Comment: I would show this for the 1st 10 questions. Many people do not remember explanations after reading them once.

Comment: It's a tangential, unspoken part of point 1, but it might be helpful to tack on a recommendation that the user step through the code with whatever debugging utility is available for their language and toolchain and report the findings in the question. My hope is that few questions will contain debugger info simply because using the debugger eliminate the posting of a lot of trivial questions.

Comment: @JonSkeet about "Any chance we could add "post code as text, not screenshots" in there?" => Happens rarely with "Code", but much-much more often with Runtime Errors... [Experience based on the small Tag ([tag:imacros]) I answer... Maybe it's "different" for other Tags/Prog_Langs...] => "Post Code + any Runtime Error as TEXT, not Screenshots" maybe... :idea:...

Comment: @OP, instead of 1-2-3-4, the Order should be 2-3-1 or maybe 3-2-1, and I have "my Doubts" if 4 is "useful" at all, only cruising for Users to ask 3 LQ-Qt's in a row, (1-Rep) Users should be allowed to ask 1 Qt per 24h and to "focus" on the Qlt (Quality) of their 1st Qt, with "neat" Follow-up etc... (And only with 1st Qt with 1 Upvoted or Accepted Answer (by the Asker), or their Qt upvoted to >=2, then "maybe" they can ask a 2nd Qt without waiting for the 24h... :idea:

Comment: Hum, "funny" we ask Users to post Code and Error(s) as Text, but Staff/@OP posted some "reproducible example" + "on topic" + more Links also as Screenshots, ah-ah...! Just saying... (Never asked a Qt, so I never "had a chance" to find/check those Links...) Item_1 could/should also have some Link with "more Info" and some good/bad Examples...

Comment: **Meta** Please add dates to "Update" headings so that we don't have to look in the edit history to find when the updates happened.

Comment: There shouldn't be more "Updates", that is how you make a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Instead, any further findings, observations, etc. should be posted as their own question. This one is busy enough as it is.

Comment: _“Many users move quickly from registration to asking their first question […]”_ — Do you have data about what users did shortly before registering? It’s very unlikely to be a significant amount, but what portion of freshly registered users read any guidance like the help center or a meta post right before registering? Also, do you have a screenshot that is less blurry? (Or is it my eyes that are just too tired?)

Comment: Is there any information available how long the experiment will run, approximately?

Comment: Are there results from this change? Or was this rolled up into the Ask Wizard saga and there are no separate results known from this change? I'd be curious as to what this dialog did for closure rate.

Answer (score 102):

If I was a new user I might find this confusing.

> About 30% of new questions do not contain enough code to pass review.

I don't want you to review my question - I want you to answer it.
And it's not clear to me what it means if my question doesn't pass review -
to us regulars, it is clear that it means it will be closed, and not get answers, but is that really obvious to a new user?

I would probably include something about the fact that the user will get no answers - as that is what they care about. Maybe something like "About 30% of new questions are closed and receive no answers due to not containing enough code".

Comment: Let me up that: *"You will get question banned for a minimum 6 months. Then it's no answers, and no questions for you! When you do get back, if you do, you'll be given one single shot and if you miss it's rinse and repeated every 6 months, forever."*

Comment: New users sometimes don't know what "closed" means, not receiving answers can happen for multiple reasons (including luck, even though "due to" suggests the reason), *too much* code is also a very common problem (so encouraging users to post as much code as possible probably isn't the best idea), and not describing the problem properly is also a common problem. I would probably opt for something like "About 30% of new questions cannot be properly answered because they don't contain enough details" (or perhaps "because they contain too much or too little code").

Comment: If only the new user knew to keep track of their question's progess in the essential first few minutes when it gets most attention and most chance of comments asking for clarifications. Maybe there is some way of telling new users about that, I am sure that SO are welcome to suggestions.

Comment: This is a good call out. We're going to revisit that language and see how it can be improved to be more clear and relevant to the new asker. I'll update the post when the new language is finalized.

Comment: +1 or if ever you'd like a more concise phrasing, saying something such as `About 30% of new questions do not contain enough code to be accepted.`? (or the long form: `About 30% of new questions do not contain enough code to be accepted, so they are closed by StackOverflow members and thereby receive no answers.`) FWIW, there wouldn't be any confusion with the notion of "accepting an answer", because here it'd just be the informal notion of "accepting a question"…

Answer (score 33):

There is one point missing:

5 . Stack Overflow is English only site and all posts must be written in English.

---

Such posts are usually closed fast, but they still take time and effort. One of the problems is that such posts get closed as "Needs details and clarity" and not being written in English as the core issue is not explicitly mentioned anywhere.

I am seeing plenty of such posts in Reopen Queue, where OP tried to edit the post, but it is still in wrong language.

Comment: I must admit, it is silly that this should even be said, but I don't disagree that people need to be reminded. In browser translators, in my opinion, are the real fault here, but considering that the volume of non-English posts isn't small, it can't go amiss.

Comment: I'm having a hard time articulating _why_, but "Stack Overflow is an English language site […]" feels more accepting than "Stack Overflow is an English only site […]".  Maybe because one emphasizes what it is, while the other emphasizes what it is not?  I know this is far from final copy, but that's my initial knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: I would guess that they took a look at the close reasons and this wasn't high enough on the list for them to include it, so they decided to keep the amount of text lower instead of adding another point that only affects a small amount of questions. But I don't have any data, so IDK.

Comment: @M.Justin How it is phrased, is not as important. What I think is important that this is mentioned somewhere on the "Ask Question" page.

Comment: It is possible to [add code in the HTML to disable browser translation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12238396/247696) in Google Chrome at least.

Comment: @MegaIng This requirement doesn't need huge amount of text and it doesn't need huge explanation. I don't know what is the exact number of such questions, but they do take our time. Just today I have already voted to close two, and in Reopen queue, I voted to keep closed one that was edited, but again in non-English.

Comment: Folks, if we do that, let's not forget our kin on pt.so, ja.so, es.so, ru.so - I do not want the first bug report to be "why posts on SO in Russian must be in English?". A similar issue already happened with review comments asking for code on non-programming sites.

Comment: **Disagree.**  There are only so many points that can be made without diluting all points, and this isn't a big enough problem to earn a place on that dialog.  Existing mechanisms are currently working well to close non-English posts quickly.  Keep the dialog focused on the much larger, less obvious quality issues.

Comment: @M.Justin The point is to reject questions not written in English. Being "accepting" is fundamentally incompatible with that goal. Even that aside, you're nitpicking and/or bikeshedding. Nobody is going to give a rat's butt about the difference in wording.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'll acknowledge nitpicking, but not bikeshedding.  It's more of a "if we did this, here's a way the suggested approach could be improved in a minor way with minimal effort."  As for "accepting", I disagree.  One can be accepting (welcoming) of someone's experience and background while rejecting their contribution.  Kindness, respect, and being welcoming are all part of the community's [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), and if that can be achieved with minimal effort while still accomplishing a task, then we should do it.

Comment: @jpmc26 "Nobody is going to give a rat's butt about the difference in wording." is clearly false, since apparently I do, and it's unlikely I'm that unique in terms of personal experience that I'm the only one.  That said, I can't imagine there are many individuals in this community — myself included — would care _all that much_ about that difference of wording.

Comment: @M.Justin Obviously, "nobody" is hyperbole to emphasize the fact that so few people care that it's not worth even having this discussion. A little intellectual honesty would be nice. And yes, the CoC and "welcoming" are equally a bunch of worthless class warfare bunk used primarily to silence particular social viewpoints, which has notably produced net harm to this community.

Comment: @jpmc26 Sorry that I didn't pick up the hyperbole; that makes sense.  I clearly projected more precision onto that statement than was intended.

Comment: I noticed an increase in the number of posts not in English recently, but apparently that was just me seeing it: [Has the discoverability of non-English Stacks Overflow been diminished recently?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413580/1115360)

Comment: If they have read everything until now, including 1 to 4, in English _and_ still went ahead to post in some other language... the problem isn't the site. Or in case they don't even understand English, writing 5) in English to tell them what to do isn't very helpful, is it. This problem can't be solved by site design, only by Darwinism. Which might take quite a while.

Comment: @Lundin Probably people use site translators, so it may not be obvious that posts must be in English.

Comment: Then it's a problem created by themselves. The majority of non-English posts here also have plenty of other problems, such as being zero effort homework copy/paste. We can't fix those people, that's a job for their parents, not SO.

Comment: Perfect example posted just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377810/ayuda-por-favor-alguien-que-sepa-muy-bien-c Translated, this question says "They left me a project in c ++ but I wouldn't know how to do it. Can anybody help me? I would be very grateful". That's it, no code, nothing. This can't be fixed by SO.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed. Some people will just ignore anything. But I have seen plenty of questions in other languages that wouldn't be that bad if posted in English, and some even try to edit them when closed, but again they miss main point and are still not in English.

Comment: There are those of us, like me, who try to edit the question and get it re-opened by translating it to English, usually with the help of a translator, and tell the OP to post in English. Even if it would get closed for another reason, that would help everyone out more than just closing it because it's not in English. I don't know Portuguese, but I'm a native English speaker, so I can fix the translator's wording and make it look less like the output of a translator. Maybe we need a "Closed because it's not in English" flag, because it's not _necessarily_ "Lacking details or clarity".

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Please don't translate posts to English only OP should do that. Writing a comment that posts should be in English is fine. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Okay, I won't in the future. Thanks for explaining it for me. I only did a couple anyway. Is is okay to _comment_ in the other language, so the OP can read it, as long as the comment is also in English?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin That should be fine.

Answer (score 32):

> For example, being a duplicate is not the top reason that first questions get closed

If I had to make an educated guess it's because finding duplicates can take a lot of work and it's frequently the case a question has multiple issues and ends up closed for other reasons.

Often SMEs will lend some guidance in the comments pinpointing to official documentation, because that may still be less work (and help out the OP all the same) than tracking down an exact duplicate.

> "Question Has Too Much Code" is the least common outcome

I see *code dumps* being posted everyday, if its relative frequency is less that is only by comparison.

You could add

> 40% of first questions do not contain enough code **-or contain too much-** to pass review.

But that would still overlook the fact that "Needs debugging details" is the only option reviewers downstream have available. I don't recall seeing any system generated comment saying "has too much code" but I've certainly voted to close a lot of questions for that reason.

Comment: "a question has multiple issues and ends up closed for other reasons" as it should be. We don't want low quality duplicates either. If there's a question that you can somehow wring it into a duplicate, but for that you need an active asker to fix other issues, fix those issues first, and then you confirm if it's a duplicate. Duplicate closure should be reserved for questions in otherwise good standing.

Comment: @Braiam if I can I always try to find a duplicate, it tends to be the most helpful for the OP. But an unfocused question would need lots of duplicate targets, a code dump would need a book, etc...

Comment: `being a duplicate is not the top reason that first questions get closed` - perhaps the current modal is working? It would be interesting if it becomes more of a problem after making it less prominent in the modal

Comment: When talking about 'not enough' or 'too much' code, I think you should slip in the phrase: `Relevant to the question' or something similar, some questions don't require code at all while other require much code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 25):

I'm pretty sure it's been demanded multiple times in the past that new users be required to go through the **Tour** before they ask their first question. While I have no particular stance on that request, it's clear that new users generally lack understanding of how Stack Overflow works, and the Tour is one of the measures to aid this issue.

I do appreciate the efforts to better guide new users, but I'm skeptical about the effect of the new modal (or any new modal - as long as it's just a modal) for multiple reasons:

- Do you track how much time it takes before users dismiss it? Apparently the modal's not being "effective" if the user dismisses it in one second.

  - What about forcing the user to read the modal before they could dismiss it? Like a 5-sec countdown?
- That their questions not meeting our standards is just one thing. That users don't follow up (properly) is another thing. For example, that new users tend to say "Thanks" in the comments instead of clicking the tick is all too common an issue for answerers. Would you / Why don't you address this in the modal update as well?

  - Similarly, what about users not responding or responding negatively to comments for improvements?

Comment: I've often wondered: How many hours would it take to adequately read the help center (in 2 years I haven't read it; has anyone)? Next the users spends 1-2 hours reading it, and actually understands it... Then how long to figure out the UI and check if he's asking a duplicate...? And then, after half a day's work; they post, **but it just goes wrong**.

Comment: Yes, that modal should have a minimum 30 minutes *"stare at it"* time, followed by a 3 hour mandatory [entrance exame](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411437). Afterwards they get to jump on [the welcome wagon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373185) and off they go on their fabulous SO adventure. *"Welcome to Stack Overflow - insert canned close vote comment here."*

Comment: @bad_coder Pushing the "mandatory reading time" up is going too far. A small amount like 5 seconds should be enough to make a difference while not being annoying. In fact, I'm inclined to believe you're (partially) trolling here.

Comment: "Do you track how much time it takes before users dismiss it?" - the longer it is, the more likely they are to not read it, which is why I don't think trying to force them to read the Tour page is likely to work (unless there's also some kind of test, but that gets complicated), and it's probably a good idea to keep the information in that dialog to the absolute highest priority problems.

Comment: We could add this to the modal:  ‘Type the words “show what you tried” in the text box below, to indicate you understand.’

Comment: @iBug ohh come on, that was a well written humorous comment. It had nothing to do with trolling. But I really liked your key idea of not allowing the modal to be dismissed in a split second. I commented because I would never have thought of that.

Comment: Don't think I have seen that modal. Does it have scrollbars? Then it would be easy to make sure new users have scrolled down to the bottom (it doesn't guaranty they have read it, of course)

Comment: _"forcing the user to read the modal... using a 5s cooldown"_ It doesn't force them to read, though. That's like when companies force people to wait/scroll through a TOS before accepting. I'm also curious if SO tracks user behavior on the modal, but I doubt these tactics motivate anyone to read if they originally didn't want to read it.

Comment: ^That. If I see a minimum time to dismiss or whatever mechanism forcing me to read something, I will go to the most extreme lengths to circumvent it, be slightly annoyed, and have a slight chuckle that I defeated it. I won't read anything if I don't want to. I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: @bad_coder I thought your comment was very obviously an exaggeration for effect, not a troll.  But if there were a countdown on the dialog then all eyes would be on the countdown, not the content.  That's exactly what happens today when I go to Youtube.

Answer (score 22):

Why is the point "Check to see if your question has already been answered" number 3, rather than 1? Having the OP check whether their question has already been answered saves them the trouble of actually asking it and having to go through the other steps.

This reminds me of help-pages that were changed from "Hitting hard on the aparatus, or pouring water over it can be detrimental to operating efficiency" to "DO NOT hit hard (...)". This dialogue assumes people will read the entire dialogue before starting to work, which might not be the best assumption.

Comment: I imagine it is so that the asker has had a chance to think more about the problem and so will be more likely to be able to google for something relevant.

Comment: I agree to your point, but I think it is a minor issue: Users only see this list once (when they attempt to ask their first quetion). So following your logic, they would only follow the first hint either way, right?

Answer (score 19):

You say in your post that question quality is measured by percentage of closed questions. Is there a specific reason for this metric being chosen, instead of say, percentage of downvoted posts, average score, or percentage of deleted posts?

<sub>Note: I'm not saying those other forms of measurement would be better, just asking why you chose the metric you did.</sub>

Comment: I think that the wording is simple and perfect. They are posing the information in the form of a [Nudge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_theory). In this case it is a [social-proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_proof) heuristic where people tend to look at the behavior of other people to help guide their own behavior. Being told that, if they follow the 30% of people who don't provide enough code, their answers will get immediately closed. But, instead, if you go with the 70% of people who do include more code, your question will have more of a chance of getting answered.

Comment: It is the most accurate and apt statistic: questions get closed because they don't meet our guidelines. There are many reasons why questions might get downvoted and/or deleted, some of which go far beyond or orthogonal to concerns about scope. No single statistical metric is going to be entirely correct, but I think this one is the best we're going to reasonably get here.

Comment: @CodyGray "questions get closed because they don't meet our guidelines" Yes, but maybe close reviewing capability is limited and not all questions that don't meet our guidelines are closed. The metric may more measure reviewing activity than true rate of close-worthy questions. The review queues are always quite full and finding duplicates is so much work and without reward really. Probably many more question are duplicates than are marked as such. A long used question quality metric was percentage of positively scoring questions.

Answer (score 18):

Speaking of numbered lists...

Why would checking that the question is on-topic go after providing a detailed description and research effort? It seems counter-intuitive to advise new users to spend their time on the problem that is inherently off-topic on Stack Overflow (and, often, on any other site of the network too).

The "check for duplicates" should go right after the topicality check - there is no point in describing the problem in detail and showing research if the core issue is already solved and is searchable.

Only after the topicality and duplicate checks should a new user start describing their problem in detail. Anything else is just wasted effort on the part of both the user and the community at large.

On a side note, the "one question at a time" does not look like a good fit for the list - it should be a general (as a paragraph) guidance for asking a question, it is not a specific action one should take after describing their problem.

We also need to address the elephant in the room - the new modal heavily implies that the user should include their failed attempts and enough code *always*. This makes the life of valid "how-to" questions (the backbone of our Q&A, frankly) even harder. The old modal included the "where appropriate" clause, please keep it in one form or the other.

Comment: Upovoted for the *backbone of our Q&A*, but it seems, we care more about *debugging problems* these days, indstead of building a repository of high relevant question and answers. Hence, most usefull close reasons have been removed...

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt yeah, it seems like a closed circle: a lot of new users ask poorly researched questions that amount to "debug my code for me", and we respond to this by demanding an MRE instead of discouraging posting debugging problems in the first place (execept valid cases). And this is one of the things that worries me about the new modal wording - too much emphasis on questions with code/failed useless attempts.

Comment: While I agree with the pecking order of issues, there are some times where there is a non-software development issue and the asker says that its a programming just because they happened to be programming at the time (3rd party api going down is the obvious and most public example).

Comment: @Braiam - true, that is why I would like to see the topicality check to go first in the modal (not that I expect the modal to have much, if any, impact). Frankly,  all those checks would be much better as an unordered list as equally important...

Answer (score 14):

[Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read/) understood something that appears lost to current StackOverflow staffers - users won't read what you put in front of them.  They'll click past it as fast as they can.

My prediction is that the A/B test will show no difference in outcome.  If anything it will be slightly worse, since the new text is slightly wordier than the old.

Comment: The question seems to indicate that we understand that people don't generally read stuff - That doesn't mean that we shouldn't present good and useful information for the few people who do read. I think the consensus here is that the new text is more descriptive than the old, so I think it's an improvement regardless.

Comment: @Catija the question acknowledges the possibility that people don't read stuff, but not in a very strong manner.  My point is that it simply doesn't matter if the new text is better than the old, because the number of people who will actually read it is too small to matter.  I would be overjoyed to be proven wrong on this one, because I don't like bad questions either.

Comment: "Assume users cannot read and, even if they could, they wouldn't want to" indeed

Answer (score 7):

Can we add something in there that discourages the use of the phrase "doesn't work"? The fact that something "doesn't work" is implied; they wouldn't be here if it did work..

I grow incredibly weary of seeing question after question that contains code that "doesn't work" with absolutely no indication of how it doesn't perform as expected

Example:

- Avoid saying "doesn't work" - say what result you get and how it is different from what you want. Give the exact text of any error messages

---

(slightly tongue in cheek) If we could also pop this up on a banner, that appears when Submit is pressed, that says

> you used the phrase 'doesn't work' - have you said exactly how your try is not what you're expecting and included the exact text of all error messages?
> <kbd>Yes I have</kbd>
> <kbd>No, I will add it</kbd>

Or as they are writing the question, highlight the phrase with a call-out bubble stemming from it saying "don't forget to.."

---

Of course, all this(everything in this entire question even) flies in the face of the UI mantra "assume users can't read, and if they could they wouldn't want to"

Comment: Mini-'+1' but I don't agree on the "and refuse to accept questions containing "doesn't work",", there are many legit Uses of "doesn't work" [... as expected [because Reason_1/Reason_2/etc...]... [after trying...]...] => ... unless you'll be happy with "deosn't work"/"doezn`t work"/"dont worrk". etc..., ah-ah...!

Comment: That's an optional but the main thrust of that point is you don't need to say something doesn't work, if you give the reasons why it doesn't work. Did you ever notice when a layman wants to sell a car they put a big sign in the windshield saying FOR SALE and when a professional wants to sell a car they put a big sign saying $9999 - the latter tells you it's for sale and also the single most important piece of info that will influence your buying decision. The former tells you nothing unless you stop and read the small print/get the number/ask for info - exhausting(hah) to do that for every car

Comment: Euh..., I'm not really into Cars..., especially with xx99.99 BS-Prices, do you maybe have some Analogy more IT-related...?, then I might understand better...

Comment: Ok; the mobile phone shop (or pawn shop/second hand shop etc) had a window display full of phones, nintendos, gadgets, whatever. They don't put a shelf of console on display and say "FOR SALE" on every one of them; they either put a price or they maybe put "reserved". You now know as you walk past, determined to get a breakfast bagel, which is for sale and what the price is. You might think "that's a bargain; I'll go buy it before someone else does". If they put "FOR SALE" on it you'd be like "well duh, you're a shop" and probably won't take the time to go in the shop, wait 5 minutes to be..

Comment: ..served, be told the price and find out "too much; I'd rather throw some cash at a breakfast bagel right now". Professionals make it easy to make that buying decision by giving you the important info you need up front. It's obvious the console is for sale/the code doesn't work because it's in a shop/on stack overflow. What we as the people looking to buy/solve a problem need is the info to quickly judge whether we can buy/help. That takes the form of a price/error message, not a "for sale"/"doesn't work". Going into every shop/commenting asking for info is wearisome

Comment: But don't get me wrong, I agree with you..., Mod and Tech Helper myself on some Tech Forum (about the "small" Tag I sometimes answer on SO ([tag:imacros])), and I regularly "bash" Users when they use "it doesn't work", as being vague and not very helpful to help them, but OK..., one "Remark" and they "elaborate" and give more Details about the "it doesn't work"... I just find preventing them to post their Qt only because they use "it doesn't work" a bit "too far"... (And I strive for much-much higher Quality on my "little" Forum than here on SO...) (OK, yep-yep, seen your 2 last Posts...)

Comment: Tweaked the answer a bit :)

Comment: " Tweaked the answer a bit :) " => Oh...!, yep-yep..., I find it much better, now you have my "full" '+1', ah-ah...! (No Change on the Votes I'm afraid, the "System" doesn't make a Difference between a "mini-Upvote" and a "fullhearted-Upvote", ah-ah...! :wink: )

Comment: I posted a Comment to the Qt "directly", about Item_1 ("Provide a detailed description of your problem and what you've tried") that could use a Link to some Guidelines with good and bad Examples (on how to ask a (good) Qt on SO), your Answer could be included in that "Guidelines" Page..., but a Popup again is "too much", I can think of at least 49 more "important" Things to include in a (first) (good) Qt, that all would justify their own Popup... Do you really want first-time Askers to have to click away 50 Popups before they can post, ah-ah...!?

Comment: Hence the last comment, but I'd be interested to hear what your 49 more important things are. This is a problem for the UX people, but basically there is a checklist of things we need to be able to answer a question effectively, and "doesn't work" is high on the list of "things an OP says that means we have to pummel them with comments asking for clarification". The other thing that is high on my list is like when they use the `sql` tag without saying what database they use. I've long wanted a system that prevents questions that only have certain tags without other qualifying tags

Comment: Yeah, 49, maybe only 19, grrr...!, but still, you get "the Principle", ah-ah...! // About "like when they use the `sql` tag without saying what database they use", well, I've "solved" that by first referring Users to my Profile and lately to the [Tag-Wiki] (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imacros/info) (for my small Tag) that I wrote myself, asking Users to mention their FCI (Full Config Info) and all Tech Info and Recommendations to include in a Qt "if they wanted some Help"... (And FCI not mentioned, I don't help, simple, ah-ah...!)

Comment: Related: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905).

Answer (score 6):

Minor layout nit-pick:

Why aren't the sentences placed starting at the same lines as the numbers? They seem vertically centred.

```
1. Bullet 1 starts here
   This text surely belongs to 1.

   Does this text belong to bullet 2?
2. Bullet 2 starts here... or does it?
   This text belongs to 2.
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick tour of the review queues will show that no matter what the new comers see they'll tend to finish off the registration quickly and get into asking question ASAP.

Still as per the staff in the comment

> present good and useful information for the few people who do read

If it's about presenting to the people who actually do read the instruction then perhaps a better idea would be to introduce a series of modals instead of a single one with `next` buttons to explain the instructions.

**Example**: The B variant contains a link to

> Minimum reproducible code

Very few people even from the the instruction followers will actually click  the link.

But if there is a modal withe a simple example picture of a sample question in my opinion would be much more effective.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider adding one more list item in there somewhere:

#### 5. Avoid asking opinion-based or recommendation questions.

With "opinion-based" being a link to either a Help Center page on the subject or a canonical Meta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post.

This is where I spend the vast majority of my close votes every day, and I *almost never* run out of questions to close vote on a given day for this reason. While I'm sure any single closure reason can lay claim to this accolade, opinion-based questions usually aren't salvageable without *completely* re-writing them to ask something else, whereas a question that lacks clarity or code might be fine once it gets a bit more information or code added to it.

Answer (score -2):

Here's more of a point of discussion, than something I am suggesting would work:

- Get the user to tick/click each point in that list.

It might be that this is too off-putting or doesn't slow down the user enough.

Comment: Man I wouldn't want to have to check a list of checkboxes when I want to ask a question. Heck, even something simple as a big _"Yea, gimme those cookies"_ is annoying already.

Comment: @Cerbrus oh definitely this could be too heavy handed